# What is wrong with my markdown to pdf bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to make a script that makes a pdf in a specific directory using pandoc and markdown. The command I am trying to run works when I run it in a shell, but not when I run it through the script. I have tried using the --verbose flag to get some debug output, but pandoc complains about not recognizing the option.

Here is my script so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IN_FILE=$1
OUT_DIR=$2
CURRENT_DATE="$(date +%d%m%Y)"
SUBSTRING=${IN_FILE%.*}

if [[ ${IN_FILE: -3} == ".md" ]]; then
    OUT_FILE=${SUBSTRING}-${CURRENT_DATE}.pdf
    pandoc -r markdown -o ${NOTES_DIR}/${OUT_DIR}/${OUT_FILE}
else
    echo "Wrong file type. Needs to be .md"
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried running it with `bash -x <your script file>`?

Comment: You haven't set the variable `NOTES_DIR`

Comment: What's `$NOTES_DIR`?

Comment: Make sure you're exporting that environment variable.

Comment: `[[ $IN_FILE == *.md ]]` is a little simpler and doesn't require counting characters.

Comment: Switch to `date +%F` so you get yyyy-mm-dd format instead. You'll thank me, many times over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to specify the in file in the call to pandoc. I just did not see it.

Here is the updated script, works fine now.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

IN_FILE=$1
OUT_DIR=$2
CURRENT_DATE="$(date +%d%m%Y)"
SUBSTRING=${IN_FILE%.*}

if [[ ${IN_FILE: -3} == ".md" ]]; then
    OUT_FILE=${SUBSTRING}-${CURRENT_DATE}.pdf
    pandoc -r markdown -o ${NOTES_DIR}/${OUT_DIR}/${OUT_FILE} ${IN_FILE}
else
    echo "Wrong file type. Needs to be .md"
fi
```